# SMTP measurement and evaluation

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to learn about how SMTP works (JAVAMAIL API).

I wrote a code that send message to a given list of adresses.

I used as properties for the SMTP server:

```
    mail.smtp.auth= true
    mail.smtp.starttls.enable=  true
    mail.smtp.host= smtp.gmail.com
    mail.smtp.port= 587
```

the send email code is:

```
public void sendEmail(String emailRecip, String subject, String texte) {

    boolean isMsgSent = false;
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });

    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
        String address = emailRecip;
        InternetAddress[] iAdressArray = InternetAddress.parse(address);

        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,iAdressArray);
        message.setSubject(subject);
        MimeBodyPart mbp1 = new MimeBodyPart();
        mbp1.setText(texte);
        Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
        mp.addBodyPart(mbp1);
        message.setContent(mp);
        Transport.send(message);
        isMsgSent = true;
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        //...
    }


}
```

This code works well, but i would like to know how can i:

> 1- calculate the avrage time of message delivery
>
> 2- calculate the impact of the size of the message
>
> 3- evaluate the impact of sending multiple messages on the same SMTP

I found many documentations that talke about those issus but i don't know how to put it in a code example, is there any other properties i must to add it to SMTP server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaMail isn't going to do this for you.  You're going to need some performance analysis tools.  Find one you like and then apply it to this task.  Or just do something simple yourself using System.currentTimeMillis() to measure the amount of time an operation takes.

See also this [JavaMail FAQ entry for sending multiple messages with a single connection](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#rptsend).

Comment: Ah i see, i will do a simple code by myself in order to evaluate all the cited issues.
Can you give me a suggestion for a performance analysis tools ?

Comment: Have you heard of Google?  :-)